# pip fails in my python virtual environments

Tags: python, virtualenv

Trying to follow this tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html.

```
$ python3 -m venv tutorial-env

$ source tutorial-env/bin/activate
```

so far so good, however:

```
(tutorial-env) $ pip --version
import: not authorized `re' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1028.
import: not authorized `sys' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1028.
from: can't read /var/mail/pip
~/src/examples/tutorial-env/bin/pip: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('
~/src/examples/tutorial-env/bin/pip: line 10: `    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])'
```

tells me something must be wrong with my python installation. I assume that should have worked.

Some information about my system installation, and the version of the software used to create that tutorial-env environment:

```
(tutorial-env) $ deactivate

$ which python3 && python3 --version
/usr/bin/python3
Python 3.5.2

$ python3 -m pip --version
pip 20.2.3 from ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

That does not seem right to me. Perhaps the problem is rooted in `/usr/bin/python3 -m pip` using dependencies under `~/.local/lib` when I would have expected it to depend on `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip`. I'm not entirely sure this is the root cause though, perhaps I just don't know how to start a virtual environment.

Update: Looking carefully, I see that `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages` does not contain a pip folder, whereas `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` by comparison does. Perhaps that is the root cause. However I have installed python3-pip via `apt-get install`.

Comment: For some reason the shebang in your pip script is shell instead of Python. It's evaluating the import statements as [ImageMagick commands](https://imagemagick.org/script/import.php). Recommend to entirely delete and recreate the venv.

Comment: You're probably right, it's not obvious which file I must edit to fix this. `head -1 $(which pip)` prints #!/usr/bin/python

Comment: Yep something's amiss there.  The shebang should have been `#!/path/to/tutorial-env/bin/python3`.  What is your OS/platform and shell?

Comment: Oh I ran this on the host. Here's the result of running this in tutorial-env: `#!/path/to/tutorial-env/bin/python3` as you would were expecting.

Comment: Does `/path/to/tutorial-env/bin/python3 -m pip --version` work?  Any change after doing `hash -r`?  What does `type pip` say?

Comment: Yes it does, and it prints `pip 8.1.1 from /path/to/tutorial-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)`. Now that's amazing, why doesn't `pip -version` work, when `python3 -m pip --version` works?

Comment: ran `hash -r` then `type pip` which printed `pip is /path/to/tutorial-env/bin/pip`

Comment: Stack overflow recommended we move this discussion to chat (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221352/discussion-between-mipnw-and-wim).

Answer (score -3):

Try re-installing both python and the virtual environment in that order

Comment: I cannot uninstall python3, it's under /usr/bin, I believe Ubuntu breaks if you remove the system-wide python.